# Why only show Alert 3 ???

Tags: jquery, html

Why only show Alert 3 ??? What is wrong??? Callback solve it? How?

**CSS:**

```
#foo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo"><div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#foo').text('Alert 1').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);

$('#foo').text('Alert 2').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);

$('#foo').text('Alert 3').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
```

Comment: Do you need this: http://jsfiddle.net/qoxw0v6p/ ?

Comment: Yes! but... I need put the alert into a "each" loop. I don't know how many alerts have.

How make this with callacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually shows 'Alert 1', then 'Alert 2', then 'Alert 3', but too fast for your eye to see it, or even your monitor to display it.
Those lines are executed sequentially. The code does not wait for line 1 and its 5000ms delay to end before executing line 2.

PHP would do this, because that's a synchronous language.

Javascript doesn't, because it's asynchronous : it can do many things at the same time.

In order to wait 5000ms for each alert, you need to set up callback functions : functions that are executed after the end of something.

```js
$('#foo')
 .text('Alert 1')
 .show()
 .delay(3000)
 .hide(0, showAlert2 )

function showAlert2(){
 $('#foo')
  .text('Alert 2')
  .show()
  .delay(3000)
  .hide(0, showAlert3 )
}

function showAlert3(){
 $('#foo')
  .text('Alert 3')
  .show()
  .delay(3000)
  .hide(0)
}
```

```css
#foo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="foo"><h1>
```

**Edit 1**

This example is ugly of course, it repeats code, but it's for educational purposes. If you had many alerts to display, you would factorize the code (and not repeat it) :

```js
var i=0;

function showAlert(){
  i++;
  $('#foo')
    .text('Alert '+i)
    .show()
    .delay(3000)
    .hide(0, showAlert)
}

showAlert(i)
```

```css
#foo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        display: none;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h1 id="foo"><h1>
```

**Edit 2**

Or again, with a list of alerts :

```js
var alerts = ['alert 1', 'alert 2', 'alert 3', 'alert 4'],
    i = 0;

function showAlert(){

  $('#foo')
    .text(alerts[i])
    .show()
    .delay(3000)
    .hide(0, showAlert)
  
  if(i>alerts.length) return;
  i++;
}

showAlert(i)
```

```css
#foo {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30px;
        display: none;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h1 id="foo"><h1>
```

Comment: Mmmmm I think is necesary callbacks

Comment: Not bad, but, if I don't know how many Alerts?? I need loop trow a list of alerts. How make Callbaks variable??